# Scan credit card info in ReactJS PWA

Tags: reactjs, react-native, progressive-web-apps

I am looking for a card scan solution for my React JS PWA. All I managed to find by googling is solutions for React Native like `react-native-cardscan`. I'm wondering if there is something similar that I could use for React JS app